# R Shiny - Filter data frame using selectInput, Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'format_vec_csv' applied to an object of class "logical"

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I'm building a dashboard with a bar graph that displays the average score in a certain skill or group of skills. The data needs to be filtered by several characteristics chosen in selectInput menus, as in this example (http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/movie-explorer.html).

Since the menu options are slightly different from the levels of the variable, I'm using the answer to this question as a guide ([Filtering from selectInput in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887482/filtering-from-selectinput-in-r-shiny)). Using the code below, I get the error in the title: "Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'format_vec_csv' applied to an object of class "logical"."

It's a class issue, which seems to be backed up by the one Google result I found for this error (https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/303). I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

Ultimately, I'd also like to have the option of presenting choices different from the levels in the data. Found this discussion ([Setting shiny selectInput from data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886800/setting-shiny-selectinput-from-data-frame)) but haven't been able to implement it.

Fake data:

```
library(dplyr)
SurvDoer <- c(rep("self", 4), rep("coach", 4), rep("mentor", 4))
Competency <- c(rep("vision", 6), rep("goals", 6))
Score <- rep(c(2,3,4,5), 3) 
fake<-data_frame(SurvDoer, Competency, Score)
```

Code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("choose_source")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      ggvisOutput("avg_bar")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Data
  db <- reactive ({
    fake <- fake %>% 
      group_by(Competency) %>% 
      summarise_(avg = interp(~ mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), x=as.name("Score")))
    data.frame(fake)
  })

  #Render selectInput
  output$choose_source <- renderUI({
        sourceOpts <- as.vector(unique(db()$SurvDoer))
        selectInput("source", "Survey Respondent", choices=sourceOpts,                             multiple=TRUE)
  })

  dataset <- reactive({
    subset(db(), SurvDoer %in% input$source)
  })

  vis <- reactive({
  dataset %>%
    ggvis(~Competency, ~avg) %>%
    layer_bars()
  })

  vis %>% bind_shiny("avg_bar")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `fake %>% group_by(Competency) %>% 
             summarise_(avg = interp(~mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x = as.name("Score")))` has no `SurvDoer` column anymore. Also, there's no need for the SE version here if you don't have a column name as a character variable.

Comment: @alistaire Thank you! I switched the order but I'm getting the same error. What do you mean by SE version?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "switched the order", but make sure the resulting data.frame has `SurvDoer`. SE stands for "standard evaluation", as opposed to NSE, i.e. "non-standard evaluation". SE dplyr functions end in `_` and take strings instead of unquoted column names; the defaults are NSE. The above could be written as just `fake %>% group_by(Competency) %>% summarise(avg = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE))`